# JavaScript: trying to create a well-behaved background job, but it gets too little time to run while rest of the system is mostly idle?

Tags: javascript, background-process

In a browser, I am trying to make a well-behaved background job like this:

```
function run() {
  var system = new System();
  setInterval(function() { system.step(); }, 0);
}
```

It doesn't matter what that System object is or what the step function does [except it needs to interact with the UI, in my case, update a canvas to run Conway's Game of Life in the background], the activity is performed slowly and I want it to run faster. But I already specified no wait time in the setInterval, and yet, when I check the profiling tool in Chrome it tells me the whole thing is 80% idle:

[image]

Is there a way to make it do less idle time and perform my job more quickly on a best effort basis? Or do I have to make my own infinite loop and then somehow yield back time to the event loop on a regular basis?

**UPDATE:** It was proposed to use requestIdleCallback, and doing that makes it actually worse. The activity is noticably slower, even if the profiling data isn't very obvious about it, but indeed the idle time has increased:

[image]

**UPDATE:** It was then proposed to use requestAnimationFrame, and I find that once again the slowness and idleness is the same as the requestIdleCallback method, and both run at about half the speed that I get from the standard setInterval.

[image]

PS: I have updated all the timings to be comparable, all three now timing about 10 seconds of the same code running. I had the suspicion that perhaps the recursive re-scheduling might be the cause for the greater slowness, but I ruled that out, as the recursive setTimeout call is about the same speed as the setInterval method, and both are about twice as fast as these new request*Callback methods.

[image]

I did find a viable solution for what I'm doing in practice, and I will provide my own answer later, but will wait for a moment longer.

**OK, unless somebody comes with another answer this here would be my FINAL UPDATE:** I have once again measured all 4 options and measured the elapsed time to complete a reasonable chunk of work. The results are here:

1. setTimeout - 31.056 s
2. setInterval - 23.424 s
3. requestIdleCallback - 68.149 s
4. requestAnimationFrame - 68.177 s

Which provides objective data to my impression above that the two new methods with request* will perform worse.

I also have my own practical solution which allows me to complete the same amount of work in 55 ms (0.055 s), i.e., > 500 times faster, and still be relatively well behaved. Will report on that in a while. But wonder what anybody else can figure out here?

Comment: What exactly is your `system.step();` doing? If it does a single step of a gol on a fairly small world, there might just not be enough to do. Especially if you want to render only one step per frame. So what are you actually trying to achieve, make it run as fast as possible (while not blocking the main thread)? How exactly do you want to interact with the canvas?

Comment: @Bergi you're getting toward the solution, I can see that. The issue seems to be that this call back is throttled by the javascript engine, to invite people to do more work in a single call-back. That's how I ultimately get the performance up by a factor of 500 or more. But I guess the theoretical question remains as to: what is the maximum work one should spend inside that callback to still be "well behaved"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I really am not trying to prevent others to get the bounty, but as you can see from the details I added to my question, none of these methods allow high rate execution of the callback.

In principle the setInterval is the most efficient way to do it, as we already do not need to re-schedule the next call back all the time. But it is a small difference only. Notably requestIdleCallback and requestAnimationFrame are the worst when you want to be rapidly called back.

So, what needs to be done is instead of executing only a tiny amount of work and then expect to be called back quickly, we need to batch up more work. Problem is we don't know exactly how much work we should batch up before it is too much. That can probably in most cases be figured out with trial and error.

Dynamically one might take timing probes to find out how quickly we are being called back again and preemptively exit the work (loop of some kind) when the time between the call-backs is expired.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really dependent on what exactly you are trying to achieve though.

For example, you could initialize your web-worker on loading the page and make it run the background-job, if need be, then communicate the progress or status of the job to the main thread of your browser. If you don't like the use of `post-message` for communication between the threads, consider user `Comlink`

1. [Web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)
2. [Comlink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/comlink)

However, if the background job you intend to do isn't something worth a web-worker. You could use the `requestIdleCallback` API. I think it fits perfectly with what you mentioned here since you can already make it recursive. You would not need a timer anymore and the browser can help you schedule the task in such a way that it doesn't affect the rendering of your page (by keeping everything with 60fps).

Something like =>

```
function run() {
 // whatever you want to keep doing
  requestIdleCallback(run)

}
```

You can read more about `requestIdleCallback` on [MDN](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-requestidlecallback).

Comment: Thanks for this idea, unfortunately the requestIdleCallback makes it worse, I updated the question to show the profiling data (comparable, letting it run 10 seconds).

Comment: Also, the WebWorker approach won't work because my background task updates a canvas on the UI.

Comment: You should consider `requestAnimationFrame` then, it's also a web API that might help

Comment: Nope, same issue, again, I updated the original question to show these results in a comparable way.